# php in_array usage

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code: ids row is like ( 54,88,15,78) a string concat of id:

```
$sql = "SELECT *, ids FROM.....";
$results = $Database->Select($sql);
$last = end($results);
foreach($results as $i){
    $userArray = explode(",",$i['ids']);
    if( in_array($_SESSION['AUTH_ID'], $userArray) ){
        echo $i['name'];
        if($last != $i)
            echo ",\n";
    }
}
```

This prints always a comma after `$i['name']`... this is wrong.. how can i fix it?? How can I count `in_array` new value??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an easier way to do this:

```
/* ... */
$logged_in[] = array();
if( in_array($_SESSION['AUTH_ID'], $userArray) ){
    $logged_in[] = $i['name'];
}

echo implode(', ', $logged_in);
```

This prints Alice, Bob

Comment: Use `implode` instead of `join` otherwise, yes. (It's a very rarely used alias of `implode` and the code already uses `explode`.)